# Self referencing loop detected for property Error in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

I am using MVVM in knockout .When I try to Searialize the object in mvc I got the following Error. Can any one please help me on this.

Error Line:    **return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultwrapper), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);**

Error
**Self referencing loop detected for property 'HotelDetails' with type 'DCL.HotelDetails'. Path 'HotelDetails[3].HotelImages[0]'.**

My Model

```
 public class HotelDetails : Entity
    {

        public HotelDetails()
    {
        this.HotelImages = new List<HotelImages>();
    } 
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid HotelChainId { get; set; }

        public virtual int OldHotel { get; set; }

        public virtual string StarRating { get; set; }

        public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual string Longtitude { get; set; }

        public virtual string Latitude { get; set; }

        public virtual string DestinationID { get; set; }

        public virtual string HotelLocation { get; set; }

        public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual string HotelArea { get; set; }

        public virtual string HotelType { get; set; }

        public virtual string HotelTheme { get; set; }


        //public virtual Destination Destination { get; set; }

        public virtual List<HotelImages> HotelImages { get; set; }

    }
```

My C# Code

```
 IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DCL.JsonMatrixModel.availableHotels>> quer =
      from ff in ddd
      from ss in ff.availableHotels
      group ss by ss.hotelCode;


            List<HotelDetails> lsthoteldetails = new List<HotelDetails>();
            List<HotelImages> lsthotelimages = new List<HotelImages>();


            HotelDetails _hoteldetails;


            foreach (var y in quer)
            {
                _hoteldetails = new HotelDetails();


                string ss = y.Key;
                _hoteldetails = db.HotelDetails.Where(x => x.Code == ss).FirstOrDefault();
                if (_hoteldetails != null)
                {
                    lsthotelimages = db.HotelImages.Where(x => x.HotelDetailsId == _hoteldetails.Id).ToList();
                    _hoteldetails.HotelImages = lsthotelimages;
                    lsthoteldetails.Add(_hoteldetails);
                }





            }
           // resultwrapper.key = "kdkdk";
            resultwrapper.LoadData();

            resultwrapper.HotelDetails = lsthoteldetails;



            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultwrapper), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Does `HotelImages` can a reference to `HotelDetails`?

Comment: yes, It can be reference to HotelDetails

Comment: OK, that causing a circular reference. Let me check the correct setting to make this work and I'll post answer

Answer (score 0):

If `HotelImages` has a reference to `HotelDetails`, then you are likely getting a circular reference. You can prevent this with the setting `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`. For example

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultwrapper, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

[Refer documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)